# Generate CSV file from SQL server and retrieve data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, csv

I am trying to generate an excel, i can get excel but some data (actually one cell content) are missing. For example: In sql server query(it should be shown in one cell under suggestions column like this in excel):

Suggestions
Type: Compliment Category:Doctor Name:Hey

However, in my excel, under column Suggestions, it only shows me - Type: Compliment, and then Category:Doctor Name:Hey are missing.
maybe my foreach is wrong or the way i retrieve data wrongly.

```
    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }

    protected void GenerateCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //First file Inpatient
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //fill up DT here
        string strQuery ="Select * from table AND Date BETWEEN @FDT AND @TDT"
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);


        string fromdate = tbStartDate.Text;
        DateTime fdt = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate);

        string todate = tbEndDate.Text;
        DateTime tdt = Convert.ToDateTime(todate);


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FDT", fdt);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TDT", tdt);

        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        //end

        for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //add separator
            sb.Append(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName + ',');
        }
        //append new line
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[k].ColumnName.Equals("CommentsSuggestions"))
                {
                    //add separator
                    sb.Append("\"" + dt.Rows[i][k].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + "\"" + ',');
                }
                else
                {
                    //add separator
                    sb.Append(dt.Rows[i][k].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
                }
            }
            //append new line
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }

         File.WriteAllText(@"C:\ExportCSV\Inpatient.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your query be

```
Select * from table WHERE Date BETWEEN @FDT AND @TDT
```

not

```
Select * from table AND Date BETWEEN @FDT AND @TDT
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt write fully, its Select *from.... where sth = sth AND Date BETWEEN '@FDT' AND '@TDT'